# How to write automation test for Google Pay integration

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, google-pay

I've been searching for a while now and couldn't find any way of writing test for google pay, I've already tried espresso (couldn't find the view) and android UIAutomator (couldn't take the screenshot). Does anyone know if this is possible? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if this is currently possible. You may have to write your tests stubbing out the Google Pay button behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Soc, I was hopping that there were some hidden way to do it, maybe I'll have to mock the behavior